# How to change position of "Toasts" in materializecss

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, materialize

I have implemented "**Toast**" from [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/dialogs.html). And I want to give some fix position to "**Toast**" message.

For workaround, I have added class and updated position, but with different screen resolution, it's appearing different location.

```
Materialize.toast('Success Message', 6000, 'success');
```

Any one have tried to change position of "Toast" message.
Is there any other way to make it consistence in every screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Override default toast css with what you need:

```
#toast-container {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10000
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #toast-container {
        min-width: 100%;
        bottom: 0%
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 992px) {
    #toast-container {
        left: 5%;
        bottom: 7%;
        max-width: 90%
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 993px) {
    #toast-container {
        top: 10%;
        right: 7%;
        max-width: 86%
    }
}
```